# Rails setting properties on the :through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider the following (contrived) example model relationship:

```
class Yolk < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :whites, through: :eggs

  # has all sorts of interesting properties, like powderiness
end

class Egg < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :yolk
  belongs_to :white

  # The egg has a color property!
end

class White < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :yolks, through: :eggs

  # has its own set of properties, such as shininess
end
```

(Note that the egg has a color property- this is important!)

If I want to add a yolk to a white (creating an egg) while setting the color property of the egg itself, how can I do it?

Given an instance of `White` with variable name `white` and an instance of `Yolk` with variable name `yolk`:

`white.yolks << yolk` doesn't allow me to set the color of the created egg,

but `Egg.create(white: white, yolk: yolk, color: 'blue')` doesn't update the variable `white.yolks` to contain the new `yolk`!

How can I create a colored egg while still updating `white.yolks`?

---

Update: I realized after thinking that in the real world you only get one yolk or white per egg; my analogy kinda falls apart there. So, to clarify the scope of the question, I'm not looking to change the relationship between items to `has_one` or make one model that holds all of the properties; just pretend that an egg can have many yolks and whites (for some reason).

Comment: In `irb` I can update the `white.yolks` variable manually by recalling whatever I used to get `white` in the first place (eg `White.last`), but this is neither convenient nor feasible within the application or its test suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to add a yolk to a white (creating an egg) while setting the color property of the egg itself, how can I do it?

Answering this question directly.

```
white.eggs.create!(yolk: yolk, color: 'blue')
```

Considering, `white` is an instance of `White`, and `yolk` is an instance of `Yolk`.

Note: You just have to add `has_many :eggs` to `White` and `Yolk` model, to query the same both way.

Comment: This works perfectly, you just have to add `has_many :eggs` to `White`. Thanks!

Comment: @Suchipi Yes. I thought you have added it, just hide that from us.. :)

Comment: I did, I just wanted to make sure this was specified for future viewers; you might want to add it to your answer.